# App Registration: one form or several forms?

Tags: registration, app

I'm currently asking for 5 pieces of information within a single page:
- email
- password
- company
- position
- full name

I've seen several implementations, some where they break this up onto several steps. I'm not sure which one to go with.

Comment: I'm not really sure we can answer that for you.  Maybe you can reword your question so that you are asking for studies regarding single- and multi-page forms and conversion rates or something to that effect? As of right now, it might be too broad or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: that's true. I guess I was wondering if anyone else has this kind of data.

Answer (score 1):

The conversational approach (one question/answer at a time) seems increasingly popular, and there's a lot to be said for it if it's well-implemented and the interaction is fairly simple-- not least because it's a much better fit for phone users.

However, I'd be wary of over-designing something as standard as this.  Most people could fill in a form like that almost unconsciously, and if you do it as a single form, many users' browsers can fill it automatically.

Also, are you sure you need to capture all this information up front?  You can register a user with just an email and password, and once they're in, entice them to fill out further profile details.  For example, if Stack Exchange required you to add a profile photo to register, you might not have bothered; but once you started participating, you added the photo voluntarily.